# Log4j - How to compress all files per month and delete old files?

Tags: apache, tomcat, logging, rotation, compression

I have these files in directory

tutu.2013-10-01.log
tutu.2013-10-02.log
...
tutu.2013-10-31.log
tutu.2013-11-01.log
tutu.2013-11-02.log
...
tutu.2013-11-30.log
tutu.2013-12-01.log
tutu.2013-12.02.log
...
tutu.2013-12.26.log

so, per month and via LOG4J, I want to :
- compress all tutu.2013-10-*.log in one only file named tutu.2013-10.gz
- compress all tutu.2013-11-*.log in one only file named tutu.2013-11.gz
- keep uncompress all the log files on current month
- and finally, delete the gz file that have more 2 months* (so, on january, the tutu.2013-10.gz will be automatically deleted)

Thank you so much

Comment: I don't think there is any magic option to make tomcat do it for you. I would simply write a script / program in my favorite language; then run it as a scheduled task / cron job (depending on your OS).